# the code does not work error: called object is not a function or function pointerr

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
    double x0, x, eps, dx, r;

    x0 = 0.60000;
    x = x0;
    eps = 0.0001;

    do {
        r = x + pow(x, 1 / 2) + pow(x, 1 / 3) - 2.5;
        dx = (r / (1 -  1 / 2 (x , -1 / 2) +  1/3 (x, -1 / 3)));
        x = (x - dx);
    } while ((abs(dx)) > eps);
          
    printf("%f %f\n", x, r);

    return 0;
}
```

*error: called object is not a function or function pointer *
the code does not work, what needs to be done to make everything right

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error message contains some hint where the error is. Please always post complete and exact error messages.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `(x,-1/2)` ? This is same as `(x,0)` which evaluates to `0`. You might want to look up the "coma operator" and also "integer division".

Comment: I would expect you get some "function abs() declared implicitely" warning as you missed to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: You should use `fabs()` instead of `abs()` anyway.

Comment: Similar to earlier comment from @Gerhardh is `pow(x, 1 / 3)` which evaluates to `1` (any value to the power `0`). It should be `pow(x, 1.0 / 3)` to extract the cube root.

Comment: Please choose some code style and use it, your indentation makes the code so hard to grasp.

Comment: Besides indentation you should make sure to place the `while` somewhere near the related `do { }`. With some empty line above and no empty line below it looks like some `while` loop with an empty body. You should avoid such confusion by making the code visually look like the logic is.

Answer (score 2):

You have tons of syntax and semantic errors:

```
pow(x, 1 / 2)
```

Here `1/2` does integer division which means that the resulting `0.5` is chopped to `0`.
To get floating point results you must ensure that at least one operand is a floating type like `1.0/2`.

Then you have a similar piece

```
1/2(x,-1/2)
```

Again, due to integer division `-1/2` evaluates to `0`.
Furthermore you are missing some operator before the brackets.
That means the compiler expects some function call.

But `2` is not a function. That is probably the place where you get your error message.

If you use `,` in other situations than a parameter list or variable definition list, it is taken as a "comma operator" that evaluates to the second operand. That means `(x,-1/2)`evaluates to `(-1/2)` which again evaluates to `0`.
In this case I have no idea what you want to achieve with that expression and cannot give some fix for that.

Finally, you use a function that is not suitable for floating point numbers and don't provide a prototype for it as well:

```
abs(dx)
```

You should use `fabs` instead.
Usage of `abs` is also broken because it requires header `stdlib.h` which you do not include.

Comment: Function application has a higher precedence than `/` so it's not looking at `1/2` as a function, but rather `2`.

Comment: You are right. Fixed that. Thank you.